# Получение JSON с Arduino сервера. Проблемы с CORS

Tags: javascript, http, https, arduino, cors

У меня есть ардуино сервер, который работает на IP *192.168.0.177*. Если перейти по этому адресу, то он возвращает данные в JSON формате. Например, в React приложении я получаю этот JSON примерно так:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([])
axios.get('http://192.168.0.177')
  .then((res) => setData(res.data))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err))
```

В самом скетче ардуино часть кода такая:

```
client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
client.println("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
client.println("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET");
client.println("Content-Type: application/json");
client.println("Connection: close");
client.println();

client.println("[");
client.println("{ \"id\": 1, \"name\": \"John\" }, ");
client.println("{ \"id\": 2, \"name\": \"Paul\" } ");
client.println("]");
```

Если запустить React приложение в локальной сети, то все работает прекрасно. У *localhost*'a ***http***, а не *https* и он отправляет запрос на ***http*** сервер и поэтому все работает.

Проблема уже появилась тогда, когда я запустил свое React приложение в глобальной сети. То есть адрес примерно такой: ***https**://app.com*. Теперь если я через ***https*** отправляю запрос на ардуино, то в консоли пишет ошибку, что нельзя отправлять запрос с *https* на *http*. Тогда я в коде React'a изменил запрос, а точнее добавил только символ 's':

```
axios.get('https://192.168.0.177')
               ^
```

Тогда уже появилась другая проблема, связанная с CORS. В консоли выводится такая ошибка:

> Запрос из постороннего источника заблокирован: Политика одного
> источника запрещает чтение удаленного ресурса на
> https://192.168.0.177/. (Причина: не удалось выполнить запрос CORS).

Я прочитал все про CORS и везде пишут, что нужно к серверу добавить заголовок "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *". Но он то все время был у меня в коде Arduino.

Простите, я не очень хорошо разбираюсь во всем этом, поэтому прошу помощи. Где я допустил ошибку?

Comment: У вас сервер должен отдавать разрешение на запрос OPTIONS. Не знаю точно, как это сделать на ардуино. Лучше зайдите в браузере(в хроме) в devTools во вклакдку Network и там посмотрите, какие запросы приходят\уходят с какими заголовками. И вставьте их в вопрос.

Comment: `GET / undefined
Host: 192.168.0.177
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Origin: https://site.com
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: https://site.com`

Comment: Под вопросом есть кнопка [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1153427/edit). Пожалуйста, добавьте инфу в вопрос в удобочитаемом виде.